# Can focused Google Maps markers be styled?

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, accessibility, google-maps-markers

I have this [form where you can enter a location](http://fiddle.jshell.net/NXhP4/), which (if Google can find it) is shown as a marker on a map. Basically I have a Google map with a marker embedded in a form; the map is surrounded with input fields.

When you tab trough the form fields, at a certain point elements within the map are focused. One of the focusable elements is the `area` in the `map` used on the marker image. On Chrome 22 and Firefox 15 I can't see any default focus styling for areas. That annoyed me, so I tried to add some styling. Even without `:focus` this is **not** working:

```
area { outline: 2px solid red; }
```

Is there a way to style focused Google maps markers?

---

**Edit**: Since styling areas does not work I tried to see if I could bind a focus event listener to the areas. There is no focus event available for [markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) in the Google Api. So, that's a dead end.

When you try to add a listener on areas (without using the Google Api), you will run into the problem that markers aren't placed synchronically and that there is no callback available in the Google Api.

You could setup a [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) to add focus listeners to new areas, but I don't like that solution a lot.

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Even if you could do this, elements Google Maps are undocumented and subject to change at any time. Depending on your usage, you might also be breaking the terms of service. Might be better to try the Google Maps API. Definitely check out the TOS before proceeding with a production app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I would say: **no**.

There is no CSS support and no support in the Google API to for example change the marker icon on focus (as markers don't have a focus event).

Answer (score -2):

Maps live in an iframe so i don't think the can be influenced by external css.

Comment: Not according to Chrome's debug tool or Firebug.

Comment: Double checked it: I was able to style the map's copyright link.

Comment: can u send a link to the page?

Comment: This is a simplified version of the described situation: http://fiddle.jshell.net/NXhP4/